# Что происходит при приведении типов?

Tags: c, c++

Если приведение в Си стиле `(float)i;` или `float(i);`, то по сути в обоих случаях вызывается конструктор и создается временный объект? Но а что в случае с указателями, если привести `int* p` к  `(float*)p`, то почему нельзя написать `float*(p)` и что делается в случае с `(float*)p`?

**UPD:**

[[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd), За `static_cast` что-то не понятно. К примеру есть Си стиль:

```
char* str = "123456789";
int* pi = (int*)str;
```

а с `static_cast` будет :

```
char* str = "123456789";
void* pv = static_cast<void*>(str);
int* pi = static_cast<int*>(pv);
```

так вот зачем к войду приводить, а не сразу к `int`?
Это промежуточное приведение сделанное потому, что в Си нету ограничений в плане присвоения указателя одного типа указателю другого типа, а в C++ есть? То есть, получается, что если написать в С++ `(int*)str`, то он будет разложен на `static_cast<void*>` и `static_cast<int*>`? А `reinterpret_cast` каким образом тогда игнорирует это ограничение в C++? Или он тоже использует `static_cast`?

```
char* str = "123456789";
int* pi = reinterpret_cast<int*>(str);
```

[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), я так понял, что в Си не будет работать это :

```
int a;
float b = float(a);
```

потому что в Си нету классов и не будет вызван конструктор, а в конструкторе неявно приведен. Но а как тогда в Си работает такое :

```
int a;
float b = (float)a;
```

ведь если в C++ при (float)a; выбирается `static_cast` или `const_cast` или `reinterpret_cast`, то что в Си происходит при `(float)a`?

Comment: Вот подробный разбор: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1255015/276994

Comment: @strol, если можно добавьте в свой вопрос фрагменты кода, описывающие типы источника и приемника и уточните где речь о Си, а где о С++.

Comment: Вот ещё подробнее:

* [`const_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast)
* [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)
* [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)
* [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)
* [C-style cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)

Comment: @strol, на Си все просто. Для такой вот функции:


    extern void f2(float);
    void f(int *pa)
    {
      static int a;
      a = *pa;
      float b = a;
      f2(b);
    }

в x64 (Intel I5-2500) GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
генерит вот такие команды:
    
            .cfi_startproc
            movl    (%rdi), %eax
            cvtsi2ss        %eax, %xmm0
            movl    %eax, a.1589(%rip)
            jmp     f2
            .cfi_endproc
    

Как видите именно для преобразования `int` в `float` используется одна *машинная инструкция* **cvtsi2ss**.

В С++ будет то же самое.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вообще-то, приведение типов — огромная тема, в ней сброшены в одну кучу и преобразования между арифметическими типами (расширение/сужение различных видов целого, преобразование между целым и плавающей запятой и обратно), и переход вверх/вниз по иерархии наследования через указатели, и динамический контроль типов времени выполнения,  и добавление/снятие модификаторов `const`/`volatile`, всё подряд. Все правила охватить — тема для раздела с исследованиями.

Продублирую ссылки на документацию:

- [`const_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast)
- [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)
- [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)
- [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)
- [`C-style cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)

---

По поводу вашего вопроса о `const_cast`: смотрите.

Вы не можете сделать `static_cast` из `char*` в `int*` по правилам, перечисленным [тут](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast). Самым подходящим могли бы быть правила 1 и 5, но поскольку нет [неявной конверсии](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) между `char*` и `int*` (`char` и `int` не являются подклассами друг друга), то и прямой `static_cast` невозможен.

С другой стороны, `static_cast` из `char*` в `void*` возможен по правилу 1, поскольку есть неявная конверсия из любого указателя на данные в `void*`. Обратная конверсия из `void*` в `int*` возможна по правилу 10.

Возникает закономерный вопрос, а зачем нужны такие ограничения? Дело в следующем. Прямая конверсия запрещена, потому что использовать полученный указатель иначе чем для того, чтобы преобразовать его назад к `char*`, вы *не имеете права* по стандарту. Это происходит вследствие так называемого *strict aliasing rule*. Лучше всего почитать подробное объяснение с указанием причин [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/276994), вкратце: если указатель указывает на `char`, вы не можете обращаться к `int`'у по этому адресу. [Единственное исключение — преобразование в `char*`.]

Поэтому язык предохраняет вас от ошибки: если вы уж написали дважды `static_cast` через `void*`, вы должны понимать, что делаете что-то специальное.

Напротив, [C-style cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) — гораздо более безалаберная штука: компилятор пробует по очереди `const_cast`, `static_cast`, `static_cast` + `const_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` + `const_cast`, и берёт первое, что подходит. Такое поведение более типично для языков типа Visual Basic'а: вы не контролируете, что именно происходит, вы говорите компилятору «короче, реши за меня сам».

---

C-style cast в C — единственный существующий вид явного приведения типов. Поскольку в нём нету семантики наследования, в нём все операции преобразования указателей являются по существу пустыми, и просто изменяют взгляд компилятора на данные по данному адресу. (Вообще, грубо говоря, C работает с байтами, а C++ — с абстрактными сущностями.) Тем не менее, *strict alisaing  rule* работает и в C.

---

Заметьте, что в C++ преобразование указателя между базовым и производным типами может приводить к изменению адреса — в отличие от C. Это означает, что `reinterpret_cast` может дать неправильный результат, даже если `static_cast` даёт правильный! То есть, нельзя бездумно использовать `reinterpret_cast` в надежде, что он всё сделает правильно. И это также объясняет, почему C-style cast не сводится к `reinterpret_cast`.