# Что делает синтаксис (type*)?

Tags: c++, синтаксис

```
uchar* ptr = (uchar*) (img->imageData + y * img->widthStep);
```

А именно: `= (type*) (...);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приведение к типу *указатель на `type`*. В старом, C-шном стиле.

Comment: а в новом плюсовом как?

Comment: @Grundy: `static_cast` или `dynamic_cast`, например

Comment: @VladD в данном случае, скорее `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @Grundy Зависит от того, **что именно требуется**. В самом общем случае это `reinterpret_cast`. Но это говорит о том, что типы совсем несовместимы. Идеально, если `static_cast` хватит. `const_cast` и `dynamic_cast` слишком уж специфичны; конечно, это приведение может и их заменить - но при этом все становится совсем небезопасным...

Comment: @alexolut: [Насколько я понимаю](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/388091/10105) (там в конце ответа нужный кусок), это их смесь. (Или [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/268977/10105).)

Answer (score -1):

(type*)pointer значит привести pointer к указателю на type.

Comment: Это фактически дубликат другого ответа