# Явное приведение типов в стиле Си и С++

Tags: c++

Узнал о способах явного приведения типов в `С++` и не совем понял чем `static_cast <int *> (p)` отличается от `(int *) p` к примеру... Допустимо и то и то - а в чем разница не знаю.

Comment: + вот еще вопрос по теме - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/268811/Что-происходит-при-приведении-типов/268977#268977

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разница между `(int *)` и `static_cast<int *>` в С++ - гигантская. Каст в стиле С, это последовательные попытки применения

- `const_cast`
- `static_cast`
- `static_cast` и потом `const_cast`
- `reinterpret_cast`
- `reinterpret_cast` и потом `const_cast`

Какой первый подойдет - тот и применяется.

Например, `static_cast` не позволит вам снять с указателя константность, а обычный С-каст - позволит.

```
const int *p = 0;
static_cast<int *>(p); // Ошибка
(int *) p;             // OK
```

В дополнение к этому, приведение типа в стиле С может корректно приводить указатель на объект класса вверх и вниз по иерархии даже тогда, когда базовый класс недоступен, т.е. игнорируя `private` и `protected` наследование (при условии, что приведение однозначно и нет виртуального наследования)

```
class A {};
class B : A {};

B *pb = 0;
static_cast<A *>(pb); // Ошибка
(A *) p;              // OK
```